# Наложить один UI элемент поверх другого

Tags: unity3d

Можно ли в юнити наложить один UI элемент поверх другого?

В моем случае - наложить панель поверх текста.

Comment: По иерархии "верхний" объект должен быть ниже в списке. Хотя, возможно, я не правильно понял Ваш вопрос.

Есть ли возможность наглядно показать, какого эффекта Вы хотите добиться?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Спасибо, получилось! Должно быть, Вы все правильно поняли)

Comment: оформил в виде "ответа".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Размещайте UI-элементы по иерархии. То, что должно отображаться выше - по иерархии должно размещаться ниже.